# How do I simplify this php script

Tags: php, mysql

Any suggestions on how I can simplify the php script below?This was my previous question: [How to check if a checkbox/ radio button is checked in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2712237/how-to-check-if-a-checkbox-radio-button-is-checked-in-php)
that is linked to this one,
What I'm trying to do here is to output the data depending on the checkbox that is checked.
But my code isn't really good, it shows 2 tables if the condition is met by the 2 results.
As you can see in the code below, any suggestions on how I can simplify this?

```
$id =  mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['idnum']);

if ( $_POST['yr'] == 'year'  and $_POST['sec'] == 'section' ){
    $result2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM student WHERE IDNO='$id'");

    echo "<table border='1'>
        <tr>
        <th>IDNO</th>
        <th>YEAR</th>
        <th>SECTION</th>

        </tr>";

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result2))
    {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['IDNO'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['YEAR'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['SECTION'] . "</td>";

        echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
}

if ( $_POST['yr'] == 'year'  and $_POST['sec'] == 'section' and  $_POST['lname'] == 'lastname'){
    $result3 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM student WHERE IDNO='$id'");

    echo "<table border='1'>
        <tr>
        <th>IDNO</th>
        <th>YEAR</th>
        <th>SECTION</th>
        <th>LASTNAME</th>

        </tr>";

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result3))
    {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['IDNO'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['YEAR'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['SECTION'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['LASTNAME'] . "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
}

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: not an answer, but you want to use `&&` instead of `and`, you need to investigate sql injection attacks, and you REALLY DO NOT WANT TO BE POSTING YOUR ROOT MYSQL PASSWORD ON THE INTERWEBS :)

Comment: Imho you shouldn't echo html tags... That's just plain ugly. Just go out of PHP, do your HTML and then start a PHP block again. But that's just a style issue.

Comment: I see no difference in your queries. Is it supposed to be equal? Or different WHERE clauses it should have?

Comment: Also, you do not learn from the previous answers. I see no sense in answering you again.

Comment: what specific answer did I not learn from?

Comment: someone edit this and remove the password.

Comment: You've been told  how to execute mysql query properly. how to handle connections, etc. about password. but your code remains unchanged

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although not a PHP person, I would do a logical based on when to include the last name column in your table. Would something like this help and keep simplified...

```
$ShowLastName = ( $_POST['yr'] == 'year'  
                 and $_POST['sec'] == 'section' 
                 and  $_POST['lname'] == 'lastname');

$id =  mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['idnum']); 
$result2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM student WHERE IDNO='$id'"); 


echo "<table border='1'> 
        <tr> 
        <th>IDNO</th> 
        <th>YEAR</th> 
        <th>SECTION</th> ";

if( $ShowLastName )
        echo "<th>LASTNAME</th> ";

echo "</tr>"; 

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result2)) 
{ 
     echo "<tr>"; 
     echo "<td>" . $row['IDNO'] . "</td>"; 
     echo "<td>" . $row['YEAR'] . "</td>"; 
     echo "<td>" . $row['SECTION'] . "</td>"; 

     if( $ShowLastName )
         echo "<td>" . $row['LASTNAME'] . "</td>"; 

     echo "</tr>"; 
} 
echo "</table>"; 

mysql_close($con); 
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should do several things:

First you should split the display code from program logic.
You really should use a template engine like [smarty](http://www.smarty.net)

In the second step you should move your database code to a separate class.

With this separation you get much clean and better to read source.
Now you can react on you different business cases better.
Use the called PHP file as Controller which acts as broker between data retrieval and output.

Answer (score 0):

You should use PHP with HTML As Follows

```
<?PHP $id =  mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['idnum']);

if ( $_POST['yr'] == 'year'  and $_POST['sec'] == 'section' ){
    $result2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM student WHERE IDNO='$id'");
?>

    <table border='1'>
        <tr>
        <th>IDNO</th>
        <th>YEAR</th>
        <th>SECTION</th>

        </tr>
<?PHP
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result2))
    {
        <tr>
        <td> <?PHP  echo $row['IDNO'] ?>
        <td> <?PHP  echo $row['YEAR'] ?></td>
        <td> <?PHP  echo $row['SECTION'] ?></td>

        </tr>
<?PHP   }  ?>
    </table>

<?PHP }

if ( $_POST['yr'] == 'year'  and $_POST['sec'] == 'section' and  $_POST['lname'] == 'lastname'){
    $result3 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM student WHERE IDNO='$id'");
 ?>
    <table border='1'>
        <tr>
        <th>IDNO</th>
        <th>YEAR</th>
        <th>SECTION</th>
        <th>LASTNAME</th>

        </tr>
<?PHP }
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result3))
    {
 ?>
        <tr>
        <td> <?PHP  echo $row['IDNO']  ?></td>
        <td> <?PHP echo $row['YEAR']  ?></td>
        <td> <?PHP echo $row['SECTION']  ?> </td>
        <td> <?PHP echo $row['LASTNAME']  ?> </td>
        </tr>";
<?PHP    }   ?>
    </table>
<?PHP }  ?>
<?PHP mysql_close($con); ?>
```

**EDITED** YOU CAN MORE SIMPLIFY AS FOLLOWS

```
<?PHP $id =  mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['idnum']);

if ( $_POST['yr'] == 'year'  and $_POST['sec'] == 'section' ){
    $result2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM student WHERE IDNO='$id'");
?>

    <table border='1'>
        <tr>
          <th>IDNO</th>
          <th>YEAR</th>
          <th>SECTION</th>
          <?PHP    if ($_POST['lname'] == 'lastname')?>   <th>LASTNAME</th> <?PHP  }   ?>
        </tr>
    <?PHP  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result2)) {  ?>
        <tr>
          <td> <?PHP  echo $row['IDNO'] ?>
          <td> <?PHP  echo $row['YEAR'] ?></td>
          <td> <?PHP  echo $row['SECTION'] ?></td>
          <?PHP    if ($_POST['lname'] == 'lastname')?>   <th><?PHP echo $row['LASTNAME']  ?></th> <?PHP  }   ?>
        </tr>
    <?PHP   }  ?>
    </table>

<?PHP } ?>

<?PHP mysql_close($con); ?>
```